# Firefox: don't allow websites to override the / (slash) key

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, search

Some websites override the behavior of the '/' key in Firefox. Normally this opens the incremental search toolbar at the bottom of the page. But on some websites it places the cursor in a search box on the site itself. How can I prevent this?

Comment: I guess an example website might help.

Comment: Arjan: https://mail.google.com/

Comment: Pressing the slash on https://mail.google.com/ works fine on my Mac. (I do have the *keyconfig* add-on installed, and the *Nightly Tester Tools* to enable that add-on; maybe that's keeping websites from stealing the keyboard shortcut then. But I did not explicitly map the slash, so I doubt that.) The question is not about websites that initially focus some input, right?

Comment: Do you have another website? The keyboard shortcuts on mail.google.com can be disabled in `Mail Settings` -> `General` -> `Keyboard Shortcuts`  which I have done (and possible @arjan has as well which is why he can't duplicate the issue either).

Comment: You can also use CTRL + F to open the seach box. ;-)

Comment: I always turn on "Search for text when I start typing" so I don't need `Ctrl+F` or `/`

Comment: I've answered over here: https://superuser.com/a/1688490/21402

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Q is definitely addressed by the comments, so I'll rehash in a useful way:

You can disable gmail's shortcuts with `Mail Settings` -> `General` -> `Keyboard Shortcuts` if that's interferring.

You can always use `ctrl`+`F` or just the `'` (apostrophe character) too.

If you have further examples, put some out there, but I haven't found this behavior.

Useful links:
[Firefox's help on searching](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Quick%20find%20bar%20opens%20when%20typing%20in%20text%20fields)
[Syntax to tweak your `about:config` data in Firefox here](http://programmerworld.net/articles/software/firefox_tips.php)

Comment: Another example: about every Confluence site in the world ;)

Comment: Other examples: Twitter, Facebook (Messages), Rally. It's so absurd to me, because the only way anyone will discover this "feature" is by trying to use / for its usual purpose! The only people who are affected by this are the ones who are frustrated by it!

Comment: This only addresses GMail. Doesn't answer the original, more general question

Answer (score 1):

I got annoyed by a website taking over my slash yet again (youtube this time), went researching and landed here, saw there was no good answer, so decided to try and figure it out.

Turns out it's not actually that hard.  Just install [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (or equivalent js userscript addon), make a New user script, paste:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           disable websites intercepting slash
// @description    "/" slash should always bring up FF quickfind
// @run-at         document-start
// @include        *
// @grant          none
// ==/UserScript==
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  e.keyCode==191 && e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  return false;
}, true);
```

Save, go reload page in question.. hey, works for me.  Created/tested on Firefox 97.  YMMV.

Fair warning, this is *barely* tested, no idea if it'll muck with unrelated browser behavior.  Will edit this post if it needs patching.